# Is there a logical algorithm to generate unique outputs for the given inputs?

Tags: assembly, 6502

I have a table of inputs that needs to output a unique formatted byte. The bytes outputted from the algorithm need to have only 1 bit on, giving 8 unique outputs. The inputs do not have to correlate with a specific output as long as each input has a unique output. The following is a list of all possible inputs and outputs.

Inputs:
-00001000
-00001001
-00000001
-00000101
-00000100
-00000110
-00000010
-00001010

Outputs:
-10000000
-01000000
-00100000
-00010000
-00001000
-00000100
-00000010
-00000001

I would like to know if there is a logical algorithm which is designed to do this. I'm currently using a lookup table for this which is not very optimized. I have access to all the operations used in 6502 assembly.

I've given my lookup table code as one possible solution in an answer, but I'm looking for something better if it exists.

Comment: Sure there is, question is, is it better. E.g. you can have a bunch of `if` statements. You can also use a reverse lookup table, that only needs 8 entries and a loop to search.

Comment: In general this is called a *perfect hash function* and there are various meta-algorithms to construct one.

Comment: Since the high 4 bits are always 0, you can use a lookup table with only 16 entries.  Actually 11 is sufficient, since that's your largest value.  That doesn't seem so bad.  Is the performance so critical that it is worth spending half an hour of your time to improve it beyond that?

Comment: Whether this is homework or not, it seems like an interesting puzzle. So your 8 given inputs should correlate to 8 different given outputs, correct?

Comment: You enumerated the inputs & outputs, but did not say if the two enumerations have index correspondence.

Comment: You can do the translation 4 bits input to 4 bits output, where the output 4 bits represent a power of 2, `n`, then compute `1 << n`.

Comment: @ErikEidt The 6502 apparently didn't have a barrel shifter, so `1 << n` requires a loop, which is not so ideal.

Comment: Also, an old-fashioned machine like the 6502 usually has memory that is relatively fast compared to the CPU.  A load from memory may be only slightly more expensive than an ALU instruction.  There is no caching, so you don't have the issue of waiting hundreds of cycles for a cache miss to be filled from DRAM. Thus a lookup table may actually be a very good choice, especially where in this case it needs only a few bytes of ROM.

Comment: @NateEldredge That's bad news :(

Comment: @NateEldredge I think 10 byte table is sufficient with a single dec.

Comment: I didn't mention it, but I do need all zeros to output all zeros.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 18 bytes, 11 cycles

A small lookup table will be the smallest, fastest and don't forget most versatile solution to your question. You can easily change how these numbers map to each other.

```
LDX input     ;  2 bytes, 3 cycles (Zero Page)
LDA lookup,X  ;  3 bytes, 5 cycles
STA output    ;  2 bytes, 3 cycles (Zero Page)

lookup:       ; 11 bytes
  .byte $00,$20,$02,$00,$08,$10,$04,$00,$80,$40,$01
```

Tip: Perhaps the first byte ($00) of the lookup table could double up as the terminating zero of some string that you need in your program anyway. That's one trick I've used more than once over the years.

### 18 bytes, 10 cycles

Shave off 1 cycle by making absolutely sure that the lookup table does not cross a page boundary (5 cycles then becomes 4 cycles).

```
LDX input     ;  2 bytes, 3 cycles (Zero Page)
LDA lookup,X  ;  3 bytes, 4 cycles
STA output    ;  2 bytes, 3 cycles (Zero Page)

lookup:       ; 11 bytes
  .byte $00,$20,$02,$00,$08,$10,$04,$00,$80,$40,$01
```

### 17 bytes, 10 cycles

Shave off 1 byte and 1 cycle by placing the lookup table on the zero page (3 bytes then becomes 2 bytes).

```
LDX input     ;  2 bytes, 3 cycles (Zero Page)
LDA lookup,X  ;  2 bytes, 4 cycles (Zero Page)
STA output    ;  2 bytes, 3 cycles (Zero Page)

lookup:       ; 11 bytes
  .byte $00,$20,$02,$00,$08,$10,$04,$00,$80,$40,$01
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the details of 6502, so this could or could not be efficient than a lookup table approach.

```
out = 1 << (in == 8 ? 7 : in & 7 ^ (in & 8) >> 2)
```

It has the following mapping for your given inputs.

```
in -> out (hex)
 8 -> 80
 9 -> 8
 1 -> 2
 5 -> 20
 4 -> 10
 6 -> 40
 2 -> 4
 a -> 1
```

The formula came out by scribbling random things on a paper, so not much logic.

---

[Test](https://godbolt.org/z/eYqT4d4qY)

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know C. Could you try explaining what this formula does in plain English? Also, the 6502 asm compiler on the website you used uses a lot of subroutines which would not be more efficient than the lookup table.

Comment: @DartAce345 It's quite interesting that you're witing 6502, and don't know C ;) I'll try to convert it to some pseudo-assembly.

Comment: I didn't expect, but an online 6502 compiler is available. I put the code in it with optimization (https://godbolt.org/z/bsax4dcP9). Note that as mentioned in the comments, this is not an efficient solution for 6502. I recommend following Nate Eldredge's solution of using a lookup table of 10 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I do not think there is a more efficient method than a lookup table.

This is the code for my lookup table. It uses 18 bytes and 11 clock cycles. The obvious flaw is that you are wasting 2 of the bytes in the lookup table and that the lookup table itself uses 11 bytes.

```
LDX input     ;Zero Page
LDA lookup,X
STA output    ;Zero Page
lookup:
  .byte $00,$20,$02,$00,$08,$10,$04,$80,$40,$01
```

Comment: If you have the memory to spare, it's hard to beat a lookup table on an old CPU like 6502 that doesn't have cache, and memory access only takes as many cycles as an ALU instruction or two.  Oh, and with the input range being limited to only 4 bits, not 8, the necessary LUT is pretty small, so would probably make sense even on a modern CPU.

Comment: Your lookup table is missing a byte! See my answer.